# A tool that will do .net builds from RTC

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, rtc

Is there a tool out there that will build .net code from an Rational Team Concert repository?
I am looking to set up a continuous integration environment for our .net stuff and we use RTC as a source repository.  I am looking for tools that will take our source code from RTC build it, run unit tests.  If the unit tests pass, push it into production (using scripts that we define... probably with MSBuild or some other scripting tool).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from RTC4, you can define a Build Definition, with a Build Engine equals to Hudson/**[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org)**.

The **[Jenkins RTC plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Concert+Plugin)** enables a two-way communication between RTC and the job scheduler Jenkins.
Jenkins can then get the sources from RTC and launch any script you want, including one building C# sources. A Job Scheduler isn't tie to a particular language: it just run any script you want, listen to the result, and in this case, send said result back to RTC, which stores it in a Build Record.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, RTC has a build definition template for Microsoft Builds. You install a Jazz Build Engine on a target build server, and then create a new build definition. For the build definition template, specify "Jazz Build for Microsoft Visual Studio Solution".

[image: Jazz Build Template for MS Studio]

Then, you can additionally add an nUnit or MSTest tab to the configuration. From there you configure the MS Build tab. 
[image: RTC Microsoft Build Definition Template]

Comment: Interesting. Is it from RTC6.0.x? +1

Comment: These images were from 6.0.6, but its been in the product since v5.